# filter stream of List<Object> by its properties that are also a List

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I have a `List<Content>` and would like to filter by the properties of a field that is a List.

Content

```
class Content {
// ...
  final List<Tag> tags;
}
```

Tag

```
class Tag {
// ...
  final String name;
  final String slug;
}
```

Coming from Angular I use

```
map(data => data.filter(a => a.tags.some(t => t.slug.includes(this.slug)))),
```

to filter by the slug property of Tag.

However this is now Dart, Flutter and rxdart.
I have so far:

```
    applicationBloc.contentOutput.map(
            (contents) => contents.where(
                    (item) => item.tags == widget.slug).toList()
    )
```

contentOutput is a BehaviorSubject's stream.

Essentially I have a few 1000 items and would like to display only content with a certain tag.

How do I filter by a property of a List of objects' properties that is a List in Flutter/Dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like:

```
  var foo = <Content>[];
  var filtered = foo
      .where((content) => content.tags.any((tag) => tag.slug == 'bingo'))
      .toList();
```

Replace the `tag.slug == whatever` predicate with whatever test you need.

Comment: I cannot use `.any`. Is it because I have a list inside my map?

Comment: If you have a list, you can do:  var filtered = foo
        .where((content) => content.tag == 'bingo')
        .toList();